# Adding frames/borders to images in Adobe

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-lightroom

So I use Lightroom very frequently to edit and export images. I do nightclub photography often and have been asked to put a frame around my photos. Obviously a creative frame, not just a white or black one. So id like to design a frame basically and then be able to batch all photos with the same frame. Now my question is : what program would be the best to do this with? I need 100+ images done with the same frame.

Thanks

Comment: there's dozens and dozens of 'frame' plugins for PhotoShop that could be automated. I'd start with google.

Comment: @Josh Ping: Photoshop is alright for this and you can use stock picture frames if you want, and use the suggestion of mrserge below to apply them. If you purchase stock images/graphics with sets of frames, you can get some in vector and they'll be easy to use individually in Photoshop. But you could also draw your frames in Illustrator; there's already some borders with textures or patterns available with it. They're very basic but that's a start if you don't like installing plugins or don't want to buy stock images/graphics.

Answer (score 1):

if you have same dimensions for all your photos, you can record Action in Photoshop and then run the action to all images.

Comment: And if they aren't the same size, you can make an action to fix that too ;)

Comment: But it won't make accurate work - cropping shold not be automatic if you want meaningful result.

Comment: I didn't mean to crop, I meant just to resize, assuming the images were already cropped.  Obviously there is not way to batch crop, that takes a human's eye.

Comment: +1 Run the action to all images: I would add to your suggestion to go even faster, do a "automate / batch" with that action!